# Are quadstores fully compatible with RDF clients?

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, sesame, triplestore

Are there any dangers in using a quadstore if you intend all your data to be accessible by RDF clients?

I ask because to my knowledge: a standards-compliant RDF client expects 3 columns of data per tuple. A quadstore, however, introduces a 4th column for the purpose of naming graphs. The graph name is a URI so can be described with its own node in another part of the graph; this could contain valuable information such as audit trail, versioning, access rights and so forth.

My concern is that triplestore clients would not be privy to this extra detail as the *link* to such data *could* be expressed at a meta-level (i.e. in the 4th column) as opposed to using additional triples.

Hoping that I'm missing something here, as quadstores seem to be the defacto implementation for most RDF stores (Sesame, Jena, Virtuoso, etc).

Comment: What do you mean by "RDF clients"?  One of the common ways to get data _from_ a triple store is using SPARQL queries (just like SQL is the typical way to get data from a database), and SPARQL makes use of named graphs, which is what that fourth column is for.  Being a quadstore doesn't mean that you're not storing triples;  it's just a way of associating a little bit of context (one IRI's worth) with each triple that you store.

Comment: An example: how would you export the content of a quadstore as N-Triples? I appreciate that to SPARQL, the "IRI identifies a resource, and the resource is represented by a graph", but what about quadstore-unaware (but still RDF-compliant) technologies like the aforementioned N-Triples serialization format?

Comment: It would depend what data you wanted to export, I suppose. You could simply dump all the triples into one bit N-Triples file.  Or you could dump each named graph to a separate N-Triples file.  Really though, if you were exporting the contents of a quadstore, you'd probably use [N-Quads](http://www.w3.org/TR/n-quads/).  It's really a question of which data you want.  It's sort of like asking whether libraries are compatible with "English-language sentence clients" because the libraries sequence English-language sentences and group them into books.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It would appear the answer is 'no: quadstores do not introduce compatibility issues'. My concern stemmed from my impression that RDF requires everyone to agree on the abstract model of triples, and that quads would at first glance appear to break this model, or at least introduce additional information that would remain invisible to those sticking to the 'triple' model. It would seem I am thinking about the extra column using too much of a 'tabular mindset', and that there are other triplestore-idiomatic ways of representing that data, other than in the row/record itself

Comment: You _are_ right that a quad store is storing quads, not triples, so a dump of a quad store isn't RDF data, _per se_.  But then again, the dump of a triple store might not be a bunch of triples, either;  it might be a bunch of optimized indices from which a bunch of triples could be recreated, or it could be something else.  The point is that triple and quad stores hold triples, sometimes with additional information about them.  You can get triples out, but you might need to specify whether you want _all_ the triples, _some_ of the triples, or something else.